# How to implement Firebase Cloud messaging in Webapp using native javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to integrate latest version of firebase cloud messaging in web application using native javascript. From documentation it look like they have moved to node js approach and i am unable to find any sample code for javascript in firebase web version 9.

i have tried to add below code in JSP file to make it run :

```
<script type="module">
    import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-app.js'

    // If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
    import { analytics } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-analytics.js'

    // Add Firebase products that you want to use
    import { auth } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-auth.js'
    import { firestore } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-firestore.js'
  </script>
```

but its throwing error "**Uncaught ReferenceError: initializeApp is not defined**".

even when i tried to add it to script file as below

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

its throwing the same error.

I am unable to understand  firebase cloud messaging integration with native JavaScript in web version 9. all code look like node js code with import statement.

Comment: If you just want to use Firebase with JavaScript then [here is a tutorial by Net Ninja](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zdvmgGsww0&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jERUGvbudErNCeSZHWUVlb.)

Comment: unfortunately its also in node js

Comment: Well what do you want it in.

Comment: sample code for web application and chrome extensions

Comment: I'm sorry its different for each language your going to have to be more specific like what language particularly